# HTTP status: 500 error on docker pull using docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

After removing and reinstalling a default machine using Docker Quickstart and VirtualBox any `docker pull` fails. Restarting `docker-machine` doesn't help.

For example:

```
~$ docker pull ubuntu:14.04
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/14.04: 
Received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: I'm having similar problems. I hope it's just a transient since its a 500 error. Here is debug output from my daemon:
DEBU[0019] Trying to pull ubuntu from https://registry-1.docker.io v2 
DEBU[0020] Error trying v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/14.04: Received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error 
DEBU[0020] Skipping v1 endpoint https://index.docker.io because v2 registry was detected

Comment: @StevenDarnell thanks. I think you're right. It's much stabler now. I'd been having a bunch of (unrelated, I think) issues with docker-machine just before this and so I (sort of thoughtlessly) assumed it was something on my end. The 500 should've been a red flag that it was something at docker.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely caused by an error at docker.io (500 should've been a red flag ;) that was intermittent. Next time double check from another machine if possible.

**Earlier thoughts:**

With the default docker-machine running, regenerating the tls certs:

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs
```

fixes the problem, sometimes, for one pull. But has also yielded:

```
 Error response from daemon: Get <url omitted>: Get <url omitted>: 
 net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```